# Text-based browser with bind-address option

Tags: web-browser, command-line

I'm looking for a command line text-based browser like Lynx, but with with the ability to select the network interface (like `wget --bind-address=1.2.3.4`).

I already tried Lynx, links, w3m, elinks with no luck. curl and wget aren't options for me because I need a full text-browser, not just a page downloader.

Comment: Could a web browser plus a proxy work for you? There aren't that many text mode web browsers but proxies are a dime a dozen, so I'd be surprised if a suitable proxy didn't exist.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes - this might help to find a workaround.

Comment: Good idea. May you suggest a proxy I can install on CentOS 6?